# How to duplicate a UIButton in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The object inherits from NSObject.

Is there a method to create a copy of it as a new object?

Comment: Why are you trying to copy a UIButton?  There may be a better path...

Comment: Is there a downside to copying a UIButton? I need to dynamically create new buttons based off of an existing one.

Comment: You duplicate a button to make, say, a row of buttons.  @JamesSkidmore Here's full code http://stackoverflow.com/a/26438692/294884

Answer (score 65, accepted):

UIButton does not conform to NSCopying, so you cannot make a copy via -copy.

However, it does conform to NSCoding, so you can archive the current instance, then unarchive a 'copy'.

```
NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: button];
UIButton *buttonCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: archivedData];
```

Afterwards, you'll have to assign any additional properties that weren't carried over in the archive (e.g. the delegate) as necessary.

Comment: Clever!  I would've probably just added -copy via a category, but this is better. =)

Comment: Isn't this a bit slow?

Answer (score 4):

`UIButton` doesn't conform to the `NSCopying` protocol, so you have copy it by hand. On the other hand, it is not a bad thing, since it is not exactly clear what does it mean to copy a button. For example, should it add the button copy to the same view the original is in? Should it fire the same methods when tapped?

Answer (score 3):

To add to Jim's answer above using a category

```
 @implementation UIButton (NSCopying)

 - (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
     NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
     UIButton *buttonCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: archivedData];
     return buttonCopy;
 }

 @end
```

if you wanted to copy all of the actions from one button to another, add something like this:

```
 for (id target in button.allTargets) {
    NSArray *actions = [button actionsForTarget:target forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    for (NSString *action in actions) {
        [newButton addTarget:target action:NSSelectorFromString(action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it implements the `NSCopying` protocol, then the `-copy` method should do the trick.

Comment: I'm trying to copy a UIButton. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can get more information about the `-copy` method and how it works with sub-objects on the ADC reference site.  As Stephen Darlington mentions, you need to implement the `NSCopying` protocol in your object.

[documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/copy)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3/4 version would be:

```
let archivedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: button as Any)
let buttonCopy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: archivedData) as? UIButton
```