# How can I make an exact replica of a UIComponent? (iPad)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uilabel

I need to create an exact copy of several `UIComponents` in my app. An example of this is a `UILabel`. I have created two `UILabels` in interface builder, which I have then linked up.

The next thing I did was as follows:

```
self.myLabel_a.text = @"Blah blah blah";
// ... and some other settings (eg. font size, colour, etc.)
self.myLabel_b = self.myLabel_a;
```

However, when I run my app I do not see the desired effect. Please can someone advice on why this is happening. I'm very sorry if this is a novice question, however I do not understand the issue here and how to fix it.

Comment: What you are experiencing is the basics of how pointers work. `myLabel_a` is pointing at a `UILabel`. You then set `myLabel_b` to `myLabel_a` which will make it also point to the same `UILabel`. You need two separate `UILabel`s and if you want them to always display the same thing you need to write code to sync them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code now just assignes references, it's not a 'copying'. In order to support real copy you need to implement [NSCopying](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. UILabel does not conform to [NSCopying](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), and you cannot just 'make a copy'.

See these questions below:

- [How to duplicate an object in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092875/how-to-duplicate-an-object-in-objective-c)
- [How to copy an object in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459598/how-to-copy-an-object-in-objective-c)